# Can I install any distro (preferably Ubuntu/Debian) with SSD drive, no legacy mode (just UEFI) and no option to switch to AHCI mode?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssd, raid

My Ubuntu installer can't see a SSD drive. I searched for a solution a bit and found people recommeding

- to switch off secure boot (it's disabled),
- to switch to legacy mode (can't, I only have uefi option),
- to switch SATA mode to AHCI (can't, it's greyed out in my bios)

So none of the typical solutions will work for me.
There is no other OS on my computer and I'd prefer not to install Windows.
It's an Acer laptop with PCie NVMe SSD drive and intel i7-9750H processor.

Comment: Blame Intel: they offer a lot of open-source Linux features, but no correct support for their SATA controller when in RAID mode. Then blame the BIOS not offering an option to switch from RAID mode, which is often useless on laptop. That said, if the BIOS is just a lack of feature rather than active prevention of feature, it appears on some (really different: mac) systems, this can be done by GRUB: https://darkfader.blogspot.com/2010/04/windows-on-intel-mac-and-ahci-mode.html . At least do tests in interactive mode

Comment: other similar link: https://www.win-raid.com/t1254f23-Enable-AHCI-when-the-BIOS-does-not-have-the-option-but-the-chipset-suport-AHCI-without-mod-BIOS.html You know it worked if the device changes ID.

Comment: Linux of course supports NVMe and UEFI. A recent enough version should just work. Do you perhaps have drive encryption enabled or anything the like?

Comment: @DanielB I could experience this when replacing some NVMe in Dell Laptop (what's the relation with SATA? no idea). The disk is just not detected at all on Linux. Only changing in the UEFI menu the controller mode from RAID to AHCI makes it discoverable in Linux. To be precise a Dell Latitude E7270 with a PM951 Samsung nvme. It's also a cause of grief when people had this done to their laptop and a year later the UEFI is reset (by changing its battery): "Linux doesn't work anymore", until told to switch back to AHCI.

Comment: Most NVMe SSDs require AHCI and UEFI mode and cannot function without either.

Answer (score -1):

After checking Acer forums I found the following:

- options to switch to AHCI is indeed greyed out
- BUT there is a hidden way to change it after pressing ctrl+s in bios

Comment: I am the original author (signed in later) and it did solve the problem